# Siemens logo Shadows and AWS IoT Timestream problem

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, amazon-timestream

I´m trying to separate my shadow data values from Siemens Logo device into correct columns - each value should be written to `Amazon Timestream` separately however they value names contains characters like dashes etc. and I´m not able to separate the values by setting SQL filter.

The best what I was able to done was to set:

```
// Rule query statement
SELECT state.reported FROM '$aws/things/HneviceIoT1/shadow/update'
```

So I was able only select all data from the shadow file update and set

```
Dimension Name: device_id
Dimension Value: ${clientId()}
```

The result in Timestream looks unusable - attached print screen

[image: AWS Screenshot]

*Any help and Ideas would be very very appreciated.*

Example of shadow document.

```
// Device Shadow state:
{
  "state": {
    "reported": {
      "AM..4:1-1": "0027",
      "I..1:1-1": "00",
      "I..1:2-1": "01",
      "Q..1:5-1": "01",
      "M..1:25-1": "01",
      "M..1:1-1": "00"
    }
  }
}

// Device Shadow metadata
{
  "metadata": {
    "reported": {
      "AM..4:1-1": {
        "timestamp": 1633104862
      },
      "I..1:1-1": {
        "timestamp": 1633104862
      },
      "I..1:2-1": {
        "timestamp": 1633104862
      },
      "Q..1:5-1": {
        "timestamp": 1633104862
      },
      "M..1:25-1": {
        "timestamp": 1633104862
      },
      "M..1:1-1": {
        "timestamp": 1633104862
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem.
The best solution I found is to use an AWS Lambda function:

1. Use an Iot rule to send your data to Lambda (set Lambda as rule destination);
2. Access your data in Lambda;
3. Save your data in Timestram using AWS SDK.

In Lambda I can access the Logo! telemetry values as a dictionary. I used C# (.Net6) but the same principle can be used with a programming language of your choice.

I created a message structure in C#:

```
public class TelemetryMsg
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>  State { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    ...
}
```

Then I can access data using C# notation:

```
public TestFunction (TelemetryMsg msg)
{
    string myData = msg.State["I..1:1-1"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this:
[AWS IoT Rule re-publish topic MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279927/aws-iot-rule-re-publish-topic-mqtt)
using Timestram as destination instead of MQTT.